# In Postgres txid_current() should return biginteger but instead an integer is returned

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres 11, according to documentation, txid_current() should return biginteger but I'm getting small integer that doesn't look like is extended by epoch counter. My txid looks like this: 1123

```
"The internal transaction ID type (xid) is 32 bits wide and wraps
around every 4 billion transactions. However, these functions 
export a 64-bit format that is extended with an “epoch” counter
so it will not wrap around during the life of an installation."
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-info.html

Am I interpreting documentation incorrectly?

Comment: How do you know 1123 is not a bigint value? Try with: `select pg_typeof(txid_current());`

Comment: The txid supposed to be extended with an epoch counter. I don't see it extended by epoch anywhere. Even if epoch is added to an ID and the sum is displayed as txid I still don't understant how it is extended since txids are serial numbers without regard to a time interval between transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has an internal 32bit xid counter which is different than the value returned by txid_current().

The txid_current() returns 64bit (bigint) in which the high bits are an epoch increment which happens once per xid wrap around.

So at every wraparound the epoch kicks in and txid_current() keeps incrementing. 
Thats why at a fresh launch of Postgres the returned txid looks like a regular integer and the epoch element is not apparent.

Answer (score 2):

The internal transaction counter in PostgreSQL is 4 bytes wide, but `txid_current()` will return a `bigint` that keeps increasing even after transaction wraparound. Think of it as an “external transaction ID”.

Comment: So how do you work this "external transaction ID" back to what is seen in pg_stat_activity, pg_locks, etc.? I'm chasing deadlocks but the deadlock error message is giving internal transaction ID values, but my app is logging the output of PG_CURRENT_XACT_ID_IF_ASSIGNED(), so I'm screwed. I don't want to have to query pg_stat_activity based on pid every time I emit a log line!

Comment: Issue converting reported, including a proposed patch here: https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1898158

Comment: Craig Ringer's answer here is also most helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622113/how-to-interpret-posgresql-txid-current-value